# Find the inverse of a matrix with variable a ≠ 0

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this matrix below and I'm trying to find it's inverse, I know I augment it with I<sub>2</sub> but I don't know where to go from that.

\begin{bmatrix}
2&1\\
a&a
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Use row operations to go from $[A\mid I] \to [I \mid A^{-1}].$

Comment: @Voks: as mentioned, Row Operations, Gaussian Elimination or simple formula: http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/sigma-matrices7-2009-1.pdf

Comment: So, multiply by 1/a to move a over to the augment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps quicker to use
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \frac1{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}
d&-b\\
-c&a
\end{bmatrix}$$

so that

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2&1\\
a&a
\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \frac1a\begin{bmatrix}
a&-1\\
-a&2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1&-\frac1a\\
-1&\frac2a
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find its determinant. By inspection, I can see that the determinant is *a*.

Then, multiply the reciprocal of the determinant of the matrix by the following

\begin{bmatrix}a&-1\\-a&2\end{bmatrix}